# google play store rejected my app due to sms permissions & sensitive information policy

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions, google-play-console, google-pay

I have made an exam preparation android app ,for registration I send OTP to the user

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

the app got rejected multiple times even though i have mentioned in the review comment that we use the sensitive information(send sms option) only for otp verification

I got the below message

> Requested permissions do not match core functionality of the app
> You declared Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler) as the core functionality of your app. However, after review, we found that your app does not match the declared use case(s). Learn more about permitted uses and exceptions.
> Please either:
> • Make changes to your app so that it meets the requirements of the declared core functionality or,
> • Select a use case that matches your app’s functionality "

Kindly someone help

[permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSAbn.png)

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to send OTP from users mobile number??

Or are you using anykind of third party service for OTP, like firebase or any bulk SMS system.
If you are using the third party service you don't need to set the SEND_SMS permission.

Please provide the details so that I can help you here...

Comment: yes  i'm using firebase for otp verification

Comment: Then you can remove the send_sms permission, you don't need it in app

Comment: I don't have to declare it ? I have a username,phone number,email address these 3 are necessary for registration while declaring should i mention this as sensitive information form? thank you ,your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the permission, and when asked about the sensitive information, mention the information that you are taking from users during registration and after it.

As per my recent experience, by just removing the permission your app will get approved.

Comment: Thank you will do the same & get back to you ! is there any way to connect to you in IM ? I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Connect me here https://www.linkedin.com/in/kushhemant/

Comment: i have removed it ! but still they have sent email saying this "Status: App Content Approved with Issues" 
'code' Issue found: Invalid Data safety section
We reviewed your app's Data safety section in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data.
SPLIT_BUNDLE 11: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID)

Comment: Would like to see the permissions and some more details of your app... you might be collecting user device details..

Comment: permissions https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSAbn.png
rejectedmail https://i.stack.imgur.com/afRCI.png
policystatus https://i.stack.imgur.com/frOqx.png
fullpermissions https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwWbC.png